# Datatable rows break only when viewed in read only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document and can add notes, once I add notes, i can make document completed by checking off the box. Once document is completed, it is in read only and users should still be able to view all the notes i.e. child rows.
I am showing all the child rows for notes on view only but when it comes to edit, I can see the notes only when i hover on flag column.

The issue here is my datatable loads and doesnt take much time to load my rows, in this case my child rows are shown only when i hover but once my document is in view only, all the child rows should be shown, and I am unable to load all the child rows and getting lines on the background, i was wondering if anyone could help me on this.

Below is the code when i access document in read only, I am getting fileType from URL

```
    if(getURLParam("filetype"))
                                {

                                    var EBB_DATA_ID=mDataProp["EBB_DATA_ID"];
                                    if(EBB_DATA_ID>0)
                                    {
                                        var tr = $('td', nRow).closest('tr');   
                                        var row = pickListSummary.row( tr );                                    
                                        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                                        tr.addClass('shown');
                                    }   


                                }

Below is the code when the document is available for adding notes and child rows are shown on hover only



 $('#pickListSummary tbody').on('mouseenter', 'td.details-control', function () {
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var row = pickListSummary.row( tr );
                        var EBB_DATA_ID=row.data().EBB_DATA_ID;
                        if(EBB_DATA_ID>0)
                        {
                            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                                // This row is already open - close it
                                row.child.hide();
                                tr.removeClass('shown');

                            }
                            else {
                                // Open this row                        
                                row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                                tr.addClass('shown');
                                //pickListSummary.ajax.reload(); 

                            }
                        }   
                    });
```

I get all the row values but getting the lines when I get drag and taking lot of time to drag and show up data

[image: Datatable load]

Comment: [Related Post by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884374/getting-cross-lines-on-load-of-datatable)

Comment: Any help that I can get ?